# Where did the expression "every last one" come from?

Tags: idioms, history

There is, after all, only one last one.  Why did it become common to say "every last one"?

Dictionary.com has a definition for last as follows:

> **8**.
>   individual; single: *The lecture won't start until every last person is seated.*

It seems plain that the definition was created because of the idiom, and not vice versa.

How was the idiom started?

Comment: [This](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=every+last+one%2Cevery+man+jack&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) (British usage) NGram suggests that we in the UK stuck with *Every [last] man-Jack* until the 1960s, even though that can only apply to people, whereas *one* can be applied to pigs, apples, pears, or cows as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot speak to its origin, but I can speak to the alleged redundancy. There is a reason it works as it does:

> Every last one took their seat
>
> The last one took their seat
>
> Everyone took their seat

All three of these sentences mean slightly different things. Referring to only the *last one* you could be talking about one person. Referring to *everyone* is too generic and, in usage, it doesn't necessarily mean every single one:

> The class will start when everyone is seated

Even after saying such, it is entirely plausible for the class to start before one or two stragglers get seated. By saying *every last one*, it is clear that every person *must* be seated.

This also holds for the usage akin to, "The strawberries were tasty; I ate every last one." This implies a much more thorough version of *all of them*. Plausibly, someone else could have eaten a few or you threw one of the nasty ones away. Using *every last one* works to reenforce the tastiness of the strawberries and the fact that I singlehandedly ate them all.

There are other phrases that work the same way:

> Every single one
>
> Each and every one

These have their own connotations — and avoid the confusion of *every last* — but they do not fully replace the connotations of *every last one*. Putting *last* in the phrase is very powerful.

---

*(The rest of this answer is not terribly important.)*

The phrase also has the advantage that it is three short words with a 2-1-1 syllable count. You can verbally morph this structure to emphasize the fact that they are all gone. *Every single one* is 2-2-1 which is workable, but doesn't quite have the same fast-slow-slow feel to it. More options are good things when it comes to timing and delivery.

This is commonly written by using periods after every word:

> I ate every. Last. One.

I personally dislike this style but noticed that advertising from the last decade or two seems fond of it.

Comment: +1 for the insight, but the origin of that usage of _last_ was my main question.  I already had had a handle on its meaning.

Comment: @drm: Sure. These thoughts can be interpreted as why I think the phrase became popular.

Comment: @MrHen, maybe actually this is also tmesis - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33155/a-whole-nother-way-of-looking-at-things/33173#33173 ?

Answer (score 4):

The [Idiom Dictionary](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/each-and-every-one) lists this as a *variant* of "each and every one" which became common from the late 1800s.

> every last one; every single one.
>
> Every individual in a group. ..
>
> All of these phrases are generally
>   used for emphasis. The first, although seemingly redundant, has
>   replaced all and every, first recorded in 1502. The first variant
>   dates from the late 1800s, and both it and the second are widely used.
>   Every mother's son (late 1500s)
>   and every man Jack (mid-1800s) are earlier versions that refer only to
>   males.

I can't answer the "Why it became common" though [Google Ngrams shows a steady spike](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=every%20last%20one&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) from 1880s to 1940s. It seems to be commonly used in writing at that time.

I can find an example from an [account in 1817 of  Memorial addresses in the House of Representatives](http://books.google.com/books?id=dpJGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22every%20last%20one%22&dq=%22every%20last%20one%22&hl=en&ei=hEIcTtKfL-6HmQWwlb32Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA)

Comment: Well, _each and every one_ and _every single one_ make sense, based on the meanings of the individual words.  However, _every last one_ has _last_ meaning _single_, which is an anomaly.

Comment: It should be noted that "every last" is not only used with "one" but a variety of nouns such as *every last drop, every last student* . [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/every#every-last_1) has "used for emphasizing that you are referring to all of the people or things in a group" eg. "We’ll make sure that every last detail is taken care of."
In this case, last does not just mean single but "all of".

Comment: Actually, _last_ there means _single_, too.  "...every _single_ detail..."

Answer (score 1):

In the expression

> Every last one

the meaning of "every" is an anomaly, but only if we deal with pure logic and if we talk about some set whose elements do not change over time or anymore.

Otherwise, in the real world, a following conversation would be perfectly normal (until the idiom; but I hope this can make a case on how idiom *could have possibly* been constructed):

> A: Did you get them all?
>   B: Yes, that was the last one.
>   A: What's this then?
>   B: Wait, let me finish... Done. That was the very last.
>   A: And this?
>   B: Oh, no! Sorry. Wait... Done!
>   A: Hm, sooo, what is it? Did you really get *every* last one this time?
>   B: Guaranteed! I checked five times.

So, in real world; or in a world where you analyze logic from a temporal perspective it is permissible to have multiple last, first or otherwise unique members of a set.

In this sense "every" does not mean individual or single, except through the idiom itself, and can<sup>1</sup> be explained with usage of nominal meanings.

---

<sup>1</sup> Maybe the proper word here is *might* rather than *can*. What I mean is that I don't have any references and that the whole illustration is just my speculation.

Comment: BTW, I don't remember saying it was redundant.

Comment: That is very much the story I was going to tell.

Comment: @drm65, I did imply that, didn't I? Sorry, you spoke of anomaly I believe; we can call it (potential) nonsense, or anomaly and I believe we can also say that 'every' is a redundant word (since every *is* one, for sets with only one element).

Comment: @Unreason: The anomaly was that _last_ meant _single_.

Comment: @drm65, yes, *single*, which in this sense is *one*, which in turn I called *redundancy*. Will edit the answer.

Comment: @Unreason: My question is not about the logical redundancy of _single one_.  It is about why _last_ means _one_ here.

Comment: @drm65, I've edited the answer again - the issue of redundancy is not really important for it.