# funny fish - etymology background?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context

I am reading translated version of *Haroun and the Sea of Stories by Salman Rushdie* and I am not sure about the meaning of *funny fish*. It was translated to my mother language as *a tricky thing*.

I know that if something is fishy it means that it is not so good. It might be then that the translation of *funny fish* is following the same roots. Is that so?

Could someone **explain the meaning** and more importantly the **etymology background** of "funny fish"?

The text from the book goes like that

> Mr Butt managed to make the Mail Coach go even faster. ' "Need to
>   stop?" ' he bellowed over his shoulder. ' "Need to go so quickly?"
>   Well, my sirs, I'll tell you this: Need's a slippery snake, that's
>   what it is. The boy here says that you,sir, Need A View Before Sunset,
>   and maybe it's so and maybe no. And some might say that the boy here
>   Needs A Mother, and maybe it's so and maybe no. And it's been said of
>   me that Butt Needs Speed, but but but it may be that my heart truly
>   needs a Different Sort Of Thrill. O, Need's a funny fish: it makes
>   people untruthful. They all suffer from it, but they will not always
>   admit.

Comment: Calling someone a 'queer fish' is an old-fashioned British colloquialism meaning a strange or eccentric person. It has nothing to do with the more recent use of 'queer' to mean homosexual. My guess is that Rushdie substituted 'funny' for 'queer' to avoid that association of ideas.

Comment: but it's not a person here. Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Kate I don't think that *Need* in this case is a person. Rushdie is just using rather unusual capitalisation.

Comment: Please do not use blue monospaced computer code formatting for things that should be set in italic. ELU does not have computer code.

Comment: One's first impulse would be to read "funny fish" as simply "odd", though it could be some sort of slang term for booze or whatever.  The @KateBunting suggestion is a good one -- being in need makes one do weird things.  It's not a common term in the US, to my knowledge.

Comment: Once you have started with *a slippery snake*, you have no choice but to continue with *a funny fish* or a similar alliteration.

Comment: "Funny fish" could also be expressed as a "strange critter," i.e. someone or something that is hard to pin down, tricky to understand.

Comment: @Mick - "I don't think that Need in this case is a person. Rushdie is just using rather unusual capitalisation." This capitalization makes sense to me if I think of certain folk tales that capitalize an animal or a concept, treating it like a person or character, for example Rabbit, Lion, Jealousy, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Funny* in this case just means *strange*, or *unusual*; and, notwithstanding Rushdie's deft use of alliteration, a *fish* just means a *thing*, as in "a kettle of fish". So, a *funny fish* is just a *strange thing*:

> Need's a strange thing: it makes people untruthful.

The use of *fish* brings to mind Shakespeare's phrase *a cold fish*, to indicate a heartless person:

> it was thought she was a woman and was turned into a **cold fish** for she would not exchange flesh with one that loved her

*A Winter's Tale*, Act 4, Scene 4

Also, there is the phrase *kettle of fish*, where *fish* refers to some unspecified object. See: [*Origin of “kettle of fish”*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46351/origin-of-kettle-of-fish).

> [**funny**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/funny) adjective (STRANGE)
>
> strange, surprising, unexpected, or difficult to explain or understand:
>
> The washing machine is making a funny noise again.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: So you think that fish means simply a `thing`? No more meaning behind it? I'd say that it got bit of negative connotation in this case.

Comment: @Radek It may come from Shakespeare's use of *cold fish* to indicate a heartless person (*A Winters Tale*). Certainly, it has a negative connotation.

Comment: I think I am getting now what I NEED :-D