# What is this an example of: "a napron" becomes "an apron"?

Tags: single-word-requests, language-evolution, metanalysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A whole nother” way of looking at things](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33155/a-whole-nother-way-of-looking-at-things)

I recently learned that the word [apron](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apron) was once apparently *napron*, but the current form has resulted from accidental morphing of *a napron* to *an apron*.  What is this kind of mistake called?  (I'd also like to know of others, if there are any.)

Comment: Really? What about JSB's excellent answer to [the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33155/a-whole-nother-way-of-looking-at-things) you asked about this before?

Comment: @Kitḫ: You are making me feel senile... though I must say that the answers I got from this question are more pertinent to it than the answers to the other question.

Comment: @Daniel: Don't feel so bad! As Martha points on the "nother" question, *"a whole nother"* is a bit daft anyway! It's more "mock-illiterate" than *metanalysis*.

Comment: In my opinion, this question about "a napron" is not  a duplicate of the earlier question about "a whole nother." In fact, one might argue "a whole nother" has more in common with constructions such as "guaran-damn-tee" than with "a napron." Accordingly, I request that this napron question be reopened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*An apron* comes from **misdivision** of *a napron*.

This incorrect division can work in other ways. Other examples include *newt* (*an ewte*), *nickname* (*a nekename*, from *an ekename*), *naught* (from *an aught*), *nuncle* (archaic; from division of *mine uncle* as *my nuncle*, and *an uncle* as *a nuncle*. Similarly for archaic *naunt*), the *adder* snake (*a nædder*).

Some also include *orange*, but the N was dropped before the word entered English, in French *une orenge* from *une norenge*.

*Daffodil* comes from the earlier *affodell*, a variant of *asphodel*. It's thought the D comes from the Dutch *de affodil*.

This also happens with names, such as *Ned* (*my Ned* from *mine Ed*) and *Nellie* (*my Nellie* from *mine Ellie*).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing) has many more examples in several languages and gives other names for the process:

> **Rebracketing** (also known as **juncture loss, junctural metanalysis, false splitting, false separation, faulty separation, misdivision**, or **refactorization**) is a common process in historical linguistics where a word originally derived from one source is broken down or bracketed into a different set of factors. It is a form of folk etymology, where the new factors may appear meaningful (e.g., *hamburger* taken to mean a *burger* with *ham*), or may seem to be the result of valid morphological processes.

Answer (score 5):

[Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=apron) calls it a **faulty separation**. Some others are *adder, umpire, orange, newt, nickname, uncle* (erroneously moving the letter *"n"* to the article *"a=an"*, or noun *"ewte=newt"*.

As @Brett points out, Danish linguist [Otto Jespersen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Jespersen) (1860-1943) coined the term [metanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metanalysis?oldid=0) for this process. But there's still debate over whether, for example, deriving the verb *to peddle* from the noun *pedlar* is a form of metanalysis, or of [back-formation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peddle).

Comment: A Fawlty separation?

Comment: @Gnawme: Nah - that's **B Fawlty** (Basil! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I love that show! Before my time, but a classic.

Comment: @Mahnax You can stream episodes of Fawlty Towers on Amazon now.

Comment: I used to think there was a disease called "ahernia".

Comment: @Gnaw Cool! My friend owns all of the episodes on DVD so I can watch them there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Jespersen called it *metanalysis.*

Comment: I believe you are [in fact correct](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/metanalysisterm.htm), but *metanalysis* may be a somewhat broader term even in the field of linguistics. Opinions differ, but I think I'd say deriving the verb *to peddle* from the noun *peddlar* is a form of metanalysis.