# What's it called when a word that starts with a vowel takes the 'n' from 'an' (the indefinite article) and puts it on the word?

Tags: etymology, articles, history

I don't exactly know how to describe it, but I've heard of this happening in English before. I'm pretty sure the word 'newt' is an example of this. From what I've heard, the word used to be 'ewt', having the indefinite article 'an', but pronunciation/scholars/ I don't know caused the word to become 'newt', having the indefinite article change from 'an' to 'a'.
I think something similar happened to the phrase 'an other'. Sometimes I hear phrases using the word 'nother' like 'a whole nother', but that may be informal. I know that 'another' is an accepted word, but I'm 99% sure it came from the phrase 'an other', but pronunciation/scholars/ I don't know changed it to 'another'.
What is this phenomenon called?

Comment: Yes, _'nother_ is informal.

Comment: For an interesting discussion of the reverse case, see [What is this an example of: "a napron" becomes "an apron"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54070/what-is-this-an-example-of-a-napron-becomes-an-apron)? Although the napron question is closed as a duplicate of a question about the phrase "a whole nother," in my view it isn't a duplicate and it ought to be reopened.

Comment: Answered at [a whole nother way of looking at things!?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33155/a-whole-nother-way-of-looking-at-things/33169#33169) and [What is this an example of? 'a napron' becomes 'an apron'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54070/what-is-this-an-example-of-a-napron-becomes-an-apron/54072#54072).

Comment: Note that it's words that start with a vowel _sound_ - e.g. an umbrella vs a user; an hour vs a hedgehog.

Comment: @
Araucaria '[T]aking two words that occur in close proximity, and re-analyzing them so that the word boundary changes position' [= _metanalysis_] seems like the answer to me. // How do _you_ explain 'a nother'?

Comment: Here's  a Youtube video about this by robwords: https://youtu.be/XBVu4CjYZmo

Answer (score 12):

OED answers this question at *[newt](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126640):*

> Variant of *eft* n.1 (see forms at that entry) with **metanalysis** (see [*N* n.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/124731)).

> From the beginning of the Middle English period, the coexistence of two forms of the indefinite article (*an* before vowels and *a* before consonants) often led to **metanalysis** (a similar phenomenon occurs in other languages where the indefinite article ends in *-n,* e.g. Dutch, German, French, Italian, etc.). Variants arising by metanalysis sometimes alliterate with words with initial *n-* in alliterative verse, and in some cases have become established as the regular modern forms (so that e.g. Middle English *a nadder* became *an adder;* compare also *apron, auger,* etc.), while conversely some vowel-initial forms have gained *n-* (so that e.g. Middle English *an ewt* became *a newt;* compare also *nickname*).

Comment: Also known as "rebracketing" and "resegmentation".

Answer (score 2):

As an earlier answer correctly responded, 'newt' resulted from **metanalysis**. The rest of a complete answer, regarding 'nother' and 'another', is not entirely other. So, you state

> I think something similar happened to the phrase 'an other'.

The phrase 'an other' became 'another' by **compounding**, no metanalysis involved:

> Origin: Formed within English, by compounding.
> (From *[OEDO](https://www.oed.com/)* 'another', entry updated for OED3 June 2022.)

Yet you also seem interested in 'nother', and particularly the phrase 'a whole nother'. So, you also say

> Sometimes I hear phrases using the word 'nother' like 'a whole nother', but that may be informal.

You are correct, 'nother' has sometimes been used informally (also known as colloquially) in "positive contexts, in senses of other: different; (the) other (of two alternatives); additional." [*OEDO* 'nother', **A.** *adj.*<sup>2</sup> *(determiner)*]. Recently, this use is "chiefly in ***a whole nother***" (the earliest quote in *OEDO* using the phrase is from 1910, the latest 1963), and **metanalysis** produced this 'nother' as a variant of 'another' (op. cit.; the latest quote in *OEDO* using the bare word in this sense is contextual evidence from the *Dictionary of Caribbean English*, 1996, reprinted in [2003](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryofcari0000unse/page/409/mode/1up)).

However, depending on which phrases you heard ("sometimes I hear phrases" you said), 'nother' may be the result not of **metanalysis** or **compounding**, but rather the result of a third linguistic process, **shortening**, or of a fourth process, **aphesis**.

**Shortening** produced another still in use 'nother', with the sense "neither" (*OEDO*, entry updated for OED3 December 2003, 'nother', "**B.** *adj.*<sup>1</sup> *(determiner)*"). *OEDO* says this sense of 'nother' is frequently found in the phrase "***neither nother***.... In later use **English regional** and **Caribbean**" (op. cit.).

I don't know if you've heard this phrase, 'neither nother', or 'nother' used in the sense of 'neither', and while it seems unlikely that you have, I hesitate to rule any possibility out without evidence one way or 'nother.

**Aphesis** produced "'nother, *pron.*<sup>3</sup> and *adj.*<sup>3</sup>" as a pronoun in the sense "[c]ontrasted with one...[a]nother one, a different one" as well as in the phrase "one 'nother", and as a determiner in the sense "[a]dditional, further" (*OEDO*, entry updated for OED3 December 2003).

The linguistic process of **aphesis** consists of the "gradual and unintentional loss of a short unaccented vowel at the beginning of a word" (*OEDO*, 'aphesis', "not yet fully updated").

Note that other senses of the **shortened** 'nother' than are discussed in the foregoing exist; I have omitted discussion of obsolete senses and senses I consider unimportant with respect to your question.

Comment: And with "a whole nother" there may be *tmesis* or ("abso-f\*\*\*ing-lutely") *expletive infixation.*