# Why are nicknames called "nicknames"?

Tags: etymology, metanalysis

Where did this term originate from? According to Etymonline.com, it originates from  O.E. *eaca*, which means to "increase". However, I can't see how the "n" got stuck in there too.

Does anyone have any relevant information?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Metanalysis strikes again.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33169/48)

The regular outcome of OE *eaca* would be *ick*, as in *ickname*. At some point *an ickname* became reanalyzed as *a nickname*, and that's how the word has reached us today.

Comment: +1. BTW, I've never met a nalysis before. Are they nice?

Comment: @Robusto, sparagus is nice but nadders are a bit dangerous

Comment: Does 'icky' follow on the same lines and owe its origins to OE *ick*?

Comment: OE eaca: an increase. What has increase to do with 'nickname'?

Comment: It is an additional name, which increases the number of names you have?

Comment: Are there any cases where an initial "n" is added or dropped for any reason other than this?

Comment: @Random832, in general the phenomenon of adding sounds without changing meaning is called "Prothesis". From the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prothesis_(linguistics) I don't see any instance of an "n" being prepended, but I do see that Samoyedic languages prepend something close (a nasal velar) to certain words that start with vowels.

Answer (score 8):

It's metanalysis from *an ickname* to *a nickname.*

Answer (score 1):

Please advise if the following erred, but it helped me to naturalise or rationalise the etymology. Each indent signifies a response to an earlier post; I omit each post's usernames for readability.

> [[Source:]](http://www.reddit.com/r/history/comments/2zgpyp/what_is_your_favorite_historical_word_origins/cpiv77i) The best one I can think of off the top of my head goes back to before last names where a thing, so people would sometimes use "eke" (pronounced like "eek") names, meaning other name. Over time, people referring to "an eke name" was eventually morphed into "a nekename," which is where we get the word nickname.
>
> > In Chaucer's Middle English, "eke" is usually translated as "also", so it would've been an "also name". eg. in the Miller's Tale, we have:
> >
> > *The Miller was a stout carl, for the nones,.
> >
> >     Ful big he was of braun, and **eek** of bones;*
> >
> > Which translates, roughly:
> >
> > *The Miller was a tough bloke for this occasion
> >
> >     He was big in his brawn, and also in his bones*

Answer (score -4):

A more natural, and logical guess by backward extrapolation would be based on *nick* rather than *ick/ eace*:

*nick: a short cut, a notch*. Hence 'nickname', a short name.

*Nick: the devil*. Whence, apart from the actual name, an endearing term for that little devil, a 'nickname'.

Comment: If you read the full [entry at etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nickname&allowed_in_frame=0) then *eaca* makes sense.

Comment: I had read that early on. And yes, it does. Did I say otherwise? What doesn't though is the down vote.

Comment: If you are guessing etymologies, you might think it is a contrast between *Nicholas* and *Nick*

Comment: Oh yes, Nick is itself a kind of nickname - I was aware of that when I wrote my answer as an alternate thought experiment.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the downvote is because you're just making something up that is directly at odds with reliable source material; the question is "what is its true etymology", not "make-up-your-own etymology".

Comment: From the movie "Top Secret": "What's your name?" - "Nick." - "Nick? What does it mean?" - "Nothing. My dad thought of it while he was shaving."

Comment: I just downvoted for the reason Hellion says. I find this answer misleading. If it is in fact meant to be an "alternate thought experiment", the place to make that clear is in the answer itself and not in the comments, by saying something like "the real etymology is explained above, but an English speaker with no knowledge of this might analyze it in the following way."