# Appropriate word for internet name of a person

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, synonyms

What is the appropriate word or phrase which means the **internet name** of a person. I mean the nickname that a person uses in almost all places on the internet like blog, IRC, forums, mailing lists etc.

Comment: it's a good question, really I think just "internet nickname" is best. I've never seen a one-word term for this.  nom de net, maybe :)

Comment: "Avatar" could be used if your profile has a character representation of the user.

Comment: Just for historical record. I've been a user of online services for more than 30 years and have determined that: "Handle" comes from BBSes. "Screen Name" comes from AOL. "Nick" comes from IRC.

Comment: "Handle" comes from CB-radio slang, which enjoyed a brief craze in the mid-70s.  BBSes picked it up several years later.

Comment: You're right! That pre-dates even BBSes. Thanks, I had forgotten completely about amateur radio. ^_^

Comment: In Korea, we just say **ID** ('아이디'), but I guess that's not widely accepted in the English speaking world.

Answer (score 89):

There are various terms for this. Once upon a time, [“screen name”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/187432/72470) would likely have been the most common.

However, it seems to me that this convention has been driven by the most pervasive websites. So, with Facebook et al's move toward encouraging the use of real names, “screen name” seems much less common (phrases such as “nickname” appear to be used now by these sites).

However, I have always thought of aliases used online as being just that (which may be why Google+ includes an option to add “aliases” to one's profile now). As a result, I have tended towards the more general term [“handle”](http://www.techterms.com/definition/handle) which was apparently derived from [CB Radio operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_(computing)) and then later popularized in use by [Bulletin-board systems](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187430/appropriate-word-for-internet-name-of-a-person#comment391292_187430).

E.g.:

> My name is “Sam,” but I often use the *handle* “halosghost.”

---

As [@DoubleDouble](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/60910/doubledouble) (and others) [suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187430/appropriate-word-for-internet-name-of-a-person/187443#comment390675_187443), the terms “username” and “profile name” might also have some relevance.
I chose not to include these in my suggestion on the grounds that they often mean something different than what I believe the OP is asking for.

Often times, the “username” refers specifically to the account itself rather than what will appear to other people online. 
A perfect example would be how Steam handles its accounts.
When you create an account you specify a username (which you use to log in) and a “display name” (another perfectly valid answer to the OP's question). No one ever actually sees your username.
Of course, not all services work this way, but many do.

“Profile name” seems more relevant to me than “username,” however it feels focused on a particular profile rather than the person's general persona.

E.g.,

> My *profile name* here (“HalosGhost”) is a variation on my typical *handle* “halosghost.”

Comment: I think "username" or "profile name" may be along the lines of "screen name" as well.

Comment: *Handle* is really the most precise word for the concept -- a name or id that a person uses in many different online environments -- but I'm not sure if it would be well understood by a general audience.  *Screen name* has the benefit of being somewhat self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely "handle" to mean a secondary name that a person has chosen for themselves as a "cyber-alias". Also, not the same as profile name/username, which are context (site) specific. Nickname is a more "every-day" alias and doesn't have the internet/cyberspace connotation of "handle".

Comment: "Screen name" appears to have the primary definition of "a user's internet name" (ref: Google), and most likely was made popular by AOL (America On-Line), arguably one of the first main ISPs (Internet Service Providers), most likely due to their aggressive marketing strategy (free floppies and CDs for everyone!). Before that, frequenting a BBS (Bulletin Board System), you were more likely asked for a "handle", and hackers often had "handles" (e.g. Hackers, 1995)-- a conjecture would be that BBSs were initially for/by hackers. If you want "hacker", use "handle", else "screen name."

Comment: A plus to "handle" is that it will be immediately understood by CB users. ;-)

Comment: It is "handle", and always has been. "Screen name" was AOL's terminology becoming a mainstream household word. "User name" is more reserved for authentication details although you may often use your handle as your user name. This answer really beats around the bush; "handle" is the word for this and exists with this precise meaning.

Comment: @beginer, I was happy to do it. But, you never accepted an answer. Are you still looking for other answers?

Answer (score 31):

I guess [screen-name](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/screen+name) is appropriate:

> Noun,  *Digital Technology*:
>
> - a unique sequence of characters that a person chooses to use for identification purposes when interacting with others online, as in computer games, instant messaging, or forums.

Source:http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/screen+name

Comment: +1 Good answer, but this site strongly favors identifying sources or authoritative support in an answer. There are several for your answer [here](http://www.onelook.com/?w=screen+name&ls=a). Consider adding one or more of these definition and a link.

Comment: I agree with "screen-name". I'd offer "online name" or even "online-id" as alternatives. And, of course, on a given site it is often known as the "User Name". I might avoid it by saying something like "My name is Corry, but online I'm known as TecBrat".

Comment: This brings up a secondary debate: one word, two, or hyphenated?  Just looking through comments on this page, I see *screenname*, *screen-name* and *screen name*.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Technically, AOL probably made "screen name" popular, so two words treated as a noun would be the correct spelling (e.g. capitalized when used in a title). Here's one such example of the "Sign On" screen from AOL: http://pontus.megapath.com/kb_20/?View=entry&EntryID=242 (third image from the top).

Comment: screen name is way too AOL.

Answer (score 16):

**Pseudonym** has meanings beyond the web, but is just as applicable to usage online as off. It's also generally more appropriate to both formal writing, and writing for non-technical audiences. It's a bit more widely understood than the alternatives, being several hundred years older and more established in the language.

(Screen Name and Handle are, as already mentioned, also both perfectly accurate and appropriate, and a bit more specific to digital interaction.)

Comment: This is a good general-purpose word, especially if you are writing for a non-tech audience.  E.g., in a (print) magazine article about a blogger, you could write: "Joseph Smith, who uses the pseudonym Bubba Joe in his online rants about rural life, has become a surprise sensation among hip young city-dwellers."  However, *pseudonym* is less applicable for a username like mine, which is a contracted version of my full name, rather than a false name.

Answer (score 15):

I suggest 'Internet handle' (but having said that, Fathima's *screen name* is a well-established term, as a Google search will quickly show).

Comment: but screen name sounds old-fashioned as if you were saying "pen name" ;)

Comment: @beginer: Interesting -- "pen name" doesn't sound old-fashioned to me!  Is there a "modern" replacement term?

Comment: @j_random_hacker , no replacement...cause `pen` itself has become an ancient thing ;D

Comment: @beginer Screen name sounds old fashioned because it was AOL terminology that stuck around because of heavy usage but is falling to the wayside as the AOL generation fades into adulthood.

Comment: @JasonC, oh thats very correct sir. +1.

Comment: The word I've always seen used for this is 'handle', which I had assumed was short for "person handle" by analogy to the programming phrase "file handle", which would have been a common usage for the people who were first creating the language around internet presence.

Answer (score 15):

***Nickname*** is the appropriate word because it is a common synonym of screenname in computing. It is used outside the internet but it became a common word in this context.

***Nick*** (short of nickname), on the other hand, is mostly used in technical contexts.

Comment: Indeed I have seen **nick** often. Actually, I am not in an English-speaking country, but the term has caught ground nevertheless.

Comment: I agree with "nick" (or maybe "usual nick" to imply that we're referring to a preferred nick used when possible).

Comment: +1 for nick; `/nick` is the [IRC command](http://www.ircbeginner.com/ircinfo/ircc-commands.html) to change your nickname/screen name/display name/handle. (Which confused a 12 y/o me: "But my name isn't Nick!")

Comment: @PatrickM lol thats right, first that came to my mind when I saw this answer was IRC.

Comment: depends on the system "handle" from the Citizens Band community was common on some uk online systems.

Comment: "Nick" and "Nickname" can also be used in contexts where "screen name" is not appropriate. Especially in gaming contexts, where the name of another player might not even be *visible* on-screen. Those environments might call for "callsign" instead, but "nick" covers both.

Comment: [But from where did *nickname* come?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64663/why-are-nicknames-called-nicknames)

Answer (score 14):

I have often seen "alias" used in this way in describing what someone is called on an Internet community.

Answer (score 11):

A moniker or handle would be an appropriate word for internet name.

Comment: Please add a reference to a trusted source.

Comment: @Honza a 'trusted source' isn't required. While it can improve an answer - especially a contentious one - the main mechanism for establishing the trustworthiness of an answer is it's score, not the number or quality of hyperlinks contained therein.

Comment: Well back in the day we certainty used "handle" and you could use Cybergypsies. by Indra Sinha as a source a number of us are credited by our handle in that book

Answer (score 9):

According to the the canonical reference for all things hackish, it's handle, nick, or screen name.

http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/handle.html

Answer (score 6):

I personally use "Alias" to reference an online user's name. It's similar to *nickname*, but the context is clearer that it's a false name.

Answer (score 4):

Another discussion is here http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2216027

'username' seems to be acknowledged as indicative without accompanying baggage.

https://www.google.com/search?q=define+username

Comment: I don't think "username" is good here. It presumes a relationship to a specific program of which the person is a user. So John Doe's username can be "j.doe" in gmail, "doe" in his company intranet, and "JohnnyD_1980" in Skype. It doesn't denote a consistent online identity the way "handle" does, it just frequently happens that the users choose their favorite handle as a username in many programms if not constrained.

Comment: I would use "username" in the context of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Handle, alias, username, nickname and screen-name are all ones that have been mentioned that I would consider.

One I haven't seen mentioned yet is: [Persona](https://www.google.com/search?%7Bgoogle:acceptedSuggestion%7Doq=persona&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=persona)

```
per·so·na
pərˈsōnə
noun
noun: persona; plural noun: personae; plural noun: personas
the aspect of someone's character that is presented to or perceived by others.
"her public persona"
a role or character adopted by an author or an actor.
synonyms:   image, face, public face, character, personality, identity, self; More
```

Comment: Persona is the total package that you put on for others. The name you identify yourself as is just a small part of that.

Comment: @JasonC While I do agree that persona can be/is "bigger" that simply an online name, at its core is `aspect of someone presented to others`. Identity is bigger than just a name, but simply being a subset (name is subset of persona) doesn't mean this can't fit as a good word/definition in the right situations.

Answer (score 2):

I use "moniker" and I've found that usage to be quite common in the tech world, although it is referred to as slang:

[**moniker:**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moniker?s=t)

> noun Slang. a person's name, especially a nickname or alias.
>
> Origin: 1850–55;  probably < Shelta mŭnnik  name (alleged to be a
>   permutation and extension of Irish ainm name); final -er  may
>   represent -er1  or, as a spelling of ə,  simply release of the k.

*(I know this choice was already mentioned, but without sourcing it. I use it regularly and it immediately came to mind when I saw the question, so I sourced it.)*

Answer (score -1):

Why not, "alter ego"? It may be rather high-toned but in my opinion it matches the use of a nickname, especially used on the internet where the anonymity is valued.

I'm interested in opinions that oppose mine though :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alter_ego

Comment: Generally, Alter Ego carries an implication of not just a new name, but a new *persona*.

Comment: It's been shown that people sometimes do act differently online when they are allowed to cloak their identity with a handle, so one's "Internet name" may very well be their "alter ego." (e.g. http://www.uh.edu/news-events/stories/2014/January/12114Santana.php). That said, alter ego would only be appropriate if one were writing a discussion about this phenomenon, and not about casual Internet usage, such as posting on a forum or social network.

Comment: I use *alter ego* with some frequency, sometimes shortened to *alter* for added caché.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on your audience, but I’ve always liked the phrase *nom de guerre*.

Comment: Well, it should be *nom de métier*, since we aren't fighting.

Comment: I've seen _nom de net_ (ab)used before.

Comment: Then I'll throw in _nom de plume_.