# term for a nickname composed of an auto-antonym

Tags: nicknames, auto-antonyms

What is the term for a contradictory nickname such as "Tiny" for a very large person?

Comment: A hypernym is 'ironicism'.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338978/etymology-of-the-nick-used-in-nickname/338983#338983

Answer (score 1):

This is an ironic nickname (or ironic appellation if you want to get all formal about it).

Here is a definition which uses the example nickname you have used in your question:

***[Ironic nickname](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IronicNickname)***

> The most famous one is probably the name "Tiny". Any guy called "Tiny"
>   will invariably be either morbidly obese or eight feet tall with more
>   muscles than a Mr Universe contest. The same is true for "Shorty" or
>   "Pipsqueak" or any variation on a name or nickname implying "very
>   small."

-- tvropes.com

An *ironic nickname* is (as the linked definition above goes on to explain) a subtrope of *[non-indicative name](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NonIndicativeName)* because it is not indicative of any actual characteristics belonging to the object it is referring to. So the type of name you have referred to is both a *non-indicative-name* and more specifically an *ironic name*.