# 'I like their another app!' - 'Other' versus 'another'; grammatical usage

Tags: adjectives

I am helping a foreign language partner with English, but she asked me a question that stumped me.

If I understand correctly, 'Other' is an adjective. 'Another' is also an adjective.

Theoretically, if they are both adjectives, then they could be switched in a sentence without having to change the syntax.

However the sentence was given to me, "I like their another app."

I told her to use, "I like their other app."

It just doesn't sound right, but I cannot find any grammatical justification for saying what I am saying.

Please help.

Comment: *Their* is a definite determiner, while *an* is an indefinite one. You simply cannot have both in a noun phrase. Once that determiner slot is filled, no others can be added.

Comment: I was not taught determiners in school. I was told that 'their' was a possessive pronoun.

Comment: I have read a few dictionaries that tell me that 'another' is an adjective. Is this incorrect?

Comment: "I have seventeen apples." You can't swap "one" for "seventeen" in that sentence without changing syntax (specifically the pluralization on "apples"), even though they're both serving as adjectives. Just because two words are the same part-of-speech doesn't mean they have an identical relationship with the surrounding words.

Comment: _Another_ is a determiner; in current English you can't have two determiners in the same NP. As you say, "determiner" is a relatively recent term (only 80 years), from the period when scholars realised that the traditional description of Latin was not necessarily adequate for all the many languages that aren't Latin. Obviously it took another fifty years for schools to notice that anything had changed.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, kind of. You can't have two *central* Determiners. But you can have loads of such words in an NP: "***half all those many** Tory MP's who commented on offshore tax avoidance are hypocritical crooks*", for example.

Comment: The critical point (as noted in the answers) is that *another* is simply a compound version of *an other*, and it should not be use anywhere where *an other* would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real evidence apart from the convention of writing it that way, that the string *another* is one word. It is two words written together as one: *an* and *other*.

If you look at it that way, the problem becomes easier to set out. English will only allow one central Determiner in a noun phrase. These are words like *a(n), the, some, my, any* and so forth. We can only have one of these words doing the central Determiner job. If we try to use two, the noun phrase will be ungrammatical:

- *the my friend
- *any the people
- *his some elephants

The reason why you cannot say *I like their another app* is because it uses two central Determiners: *their* and *an*:

- I like their orange dog.
- I like their other app.
- I like their baby elephant.
- *I like their an orange dog.
- *I like their an other app.
- *I like their a baby elephant.

In the second from last example, the convention is to write *another* as a single word, but that's because English is weird. (I mean just look at the word *weird* ...)

Comment: Well, one bit of evidence that "another" is not just "an other" is that many people can divide "another" into "a nother," like in "a whole nother," but most of these people cannot use "nother" in place of "other" in other contexts.

Comment: @sumelic  Actually, [that's a whole nother story!!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247785/is-a-whole-nother-grammatical/257581#257581)

Answer (score 1):

Saying *another* after *their* is a bit like saying "next" when you haven't even started.  You need a first before you start on a second.  Use *another* only when adding to some other thing.

You're both right.  *Another* is a possessive pronoun and a determiner.

> **determiner**
>
> A determiner (also called determinative) is a word, phrase, or affix that occurs together with a noun or noun phrase and serves to express the reference of that noun or noun phrase in the context.
>
> [wikipedia: determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner)

> **another**
>
> an·oth·er
>
> əˈnəT͟Hər
>
> determiner & pronoun
>
> determiner: another; pronoun: another
>
> 1. used to refer to an **additional** person or thing of the same type as one already mentioned or known about; one more; a further.
>
> "have another drink"
>
> synonyms:  one more, a further, an additional
>
> "have another drink"
>
> used with a proper name to indicate someone or something's similarity to the person or event specified.
>
> "they said she was another Jennifer Aniston"
>
> 2. used to refer to a different person or thing from one already mentioned or known about.
>
> "come back another day"
>
> used to refer to someone sharing an attribute in common with the person already mentioned.
>
> "his kiss with another man caused a tabloid rumpus"
>
> [google: define another](https://www.google.com/search?q=another&oq=another&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=another+define)

Comment: It's awkward even if there's a first - e.g. "He likes their first app and their another app". "He likes their first app and their *other* app" is fine. though.

Comment: The important point, as the others have noted, is that *another* is simply a compound version of *an other*, and hence should not be used anywhere where *an other* would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's not deal with nomenclature in grammar for a moment unless the "grammatical justification" you're looking for is just some name tags such as 'adjective', 'determiner', etc. I hope you aren't, because that's not what's important. What's important is the meaning of the word 'another', I think.

As Araucaria said, another means "an other," and it used to be written that way long time ago. Assuming that it still retains its original meaning, it's rather a simple matter to explain why this sentence doesn't work.

> *I like their another app.

Because all you have to explain now is why "their" may not come before "a" or "an". In other words, you only have to explain why the following sentence doesn't work.

> *I like their an app.

And here's one way to explain it in case you need one. Once you've spoken *their*, all you need to add is what "they" have in possession, e.g., *app*. But adding *an* before *app* sort of contradicts your having spoken *their* in the first place, because *an app* contradicts the initial setting that *app* is in "their" possession.