# Why are 'at least' and 'a lot' not single words?

Tags: etymology, phrases, nouns, word-usage, adverbs

I constantly have trouble with spelling the word-phrases ‘at least’ and ‘a lot’ .. they both should be a single word in my mind, which isn’t correct.

They both seem to just be a single unit of meaning.

It’s an English idiom thing that I just continually stumble over. Anyone able to correct that in my head once and for all – much appreciated!

From the comments, I understand that I may have oversimplified in saying that 'a lot' and 'at least' were pairs of words. That being the case, I'd update my question as to why there is a space in that word, and if they are part of a larger set of words/lexemes that are similarly constructed.

*Also, this is my first question, so if anyone has feedback on the tags I used, that would also be welcome. I wondered about applying the tag ‘grammatical-number’ for instance, but that didn’t seem as correct as the five I chose.. not sure though.*

I understand I checked off an answer too quickly - I wish there were a way to accept multiple answers! Next time I'll wait longer though.

Comment: Linguist David Crystal introduced the term 'lexeme' for 'a string of 1 or more orthographic words carrying a base unit of meaning'. So _go, goes, going, gone, went_ constitute 1 lexeme, and _particle board, particle-board, particleboard_ another one. More complicated examples are _ship of the desert_ when used as a synonym for _camel_, and _come to_ where this is the multi-word verb meaning 'regain consciousness'. Compound prepositions such as _on top of_ (compare the old-fashioned near-synonym 'atop' and German 'auf') also qualify. Note that multi-word lexemes exist, ...

Comment: and that English is idiosyncratic (The box is _on top of_ the table, **but** The box is _under/beneath_ the table). 'On top of' is unremarkable, and as correct grammatically (and as idiomatic) as 'on' or 'underneath'.

Comment: I suspect the reason is that there are two forms: singular "lot", which is determined by "a", and plural "lots", which does not take a determiner.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for introducing me to 'lexeme', I hadn't heard of that yet! All your examples are fascinating and helpful. Much appreciated.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I agree. And it feels like 'a lot' refers to a smaller quantity of something than 'lots', right? Thanks!

Comment: In their use as non-count quantification nouns, I don't think there's any difference between "A lot of mistakes were made" vs "Lots of mistakes were made".

Comment: @BillJ Oh ok. I guess I had pegged 'a lot' as 5-10 approximately (maybe 15), and 'lots' as being like 12-15 but also applicable to higher quantities. Probably idiosyncratic to where I've seen them both used though.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, *a lot* is definitely two words, because the noun *lot* there can take a small number of modifiers: *a **whole** lot bigger* / *not an **awful** lot bigger* / *didn’t make a **huge** lot of difference*. Always best to wait a day or two before selecting an answer!]

Comment: Set phrases have a habit of getting smushed together in English. If they don't get worn down straight into contractions (and even then in the case of cannot), you might find the  phrase losing all its spaces, and even some letters as in the case of fulfil (full + fill) or al- compounds like also (all + so) or altogether (all + together). Even three word phrases aren't immune, consider "nevertheless".

Comment: If you merge “at least” into one word, would you do the same for “at most”, “at best”, “at worst”, etc? Would you extend this to all prepositional phrases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're certainly [not the first to feel an urge to merge](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) "a lot" into "alot." Maybe the most revealing question would be, *why* does it feel like "it should be a single word"?

It's easy enough to explain why these examples are two words. Take "at least": they're just two words, just doing their things. We might have said "at the least," or any other wordier construction using "at": "at the very latest," "at a hazard," and not feel compelled to merge these phrases into a single word. Similarly, "a lot" is, well, a **lot**, a noun in its own right, which [came from](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lot#etymonline_v_14542) the idea of a portion or share (and "a lot" has come to imply a *large* portion). We might use "a" with any other noun: "a multitude," "a plethora," etc., and not go around creating such mutant monsters as "abunch."

So far so good, but wait; many pairs of small words *have* successfully gotten hitched. "Some thing," "any thing," and maybe the most parallel example, "a while"—why do these get to be *something*, *anything*, and *awhile*, but the poor old *alot* gets mocked and persecuted? I don't have any better answer to that than... languages move in mysterious ways. Accepted usage is what we use and what we accept. Maybe the *alot* (and maybe even the *atleast* and *atmost*?) will have their day... someday.

Comment: Note, for some of these mashups, the two-word and one-word versions get different uses, like ["a while" vs "awhile"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/awhile-usage) or ["every day" vs "everyday"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/video/everyday-vs-every-day-difference). For others, though, like "something," the merged form has so taken over the meaning of the two-word phrase that the two-word is squeezed into a corner, existing only for usages that emphasize the two words ("It's some... some *thing*!!").

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Yes, that inconsistency you highlight is what perplexes me.. something, anything, also sometimes are all single words. Also I think I like 'alot' better than 'a lot' because 'lot' has so many different meanings. I'll try to stay on track with current usage. Thanks!

Comment: @4dcndn Feel free to campaign for its acceptance (I would say start a campaign, but I bet it exists already). Many quixotic crusaders have shed ink trying to bend the arc of linguistic evolution toward common sense (I'm looking at you, George Bernard Shaw), usually with little result, but... why not!

Comment: *A lot* is definitely two words, because the noun *lot* there can take a small number of modifiers: *a **whole** lot bigger* / *not an **awful** lot bigger* / *didn’t make a **huge** lot of difference*. Notice that the indefinite article changes to *an before a vowel*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. And yet, "another" is one word, despite passing this same test ("a whole other thing")

Comment: @NoName (And then there's the colloquial "a whole 'nuther thing," which gets the best of both words...)

Comment: @AndyBonner Actually, "whole nother" uses the old and well established 13th century determinative "nother" People often mistakenly take to be a bastardisation of "an other" with an infix! It [isn't!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247785/is-a-whole-nother-grammatical/257581#257581)

Comment: @NoName But is *another* one word in the actual language (as opposed to the orthography)? I think not!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Then what's stopping us from writing "alot" if not this test?

Comment: @NoName It doesn't matter what we write, really. That's just convention. It can change overnight. There's no wrong or right of it.  :)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. So long as we agree!

Comment: The "a-" could also, theoretically, stem from the \*ga-prefix, cp. *aware, enough, yclept". In addition the origin of "lot" is uncertain, and the supposed derivation of the quantificative sense is speculative. How does your answer address those concerns? It doesn't, simply, because you are not even a ware! But at least you are a awarewolf about the arbitrary spelling.

Comment: @vectory Thanks, I wasn't aware of the etymology of the "a-" prefix; I'd like to find out more about that. I certainly make no claim to address all concerns; in fact, although the question has the "etymology" tag, it isn't really brought up in the question. Meanwhile, I hope we can stay careful about how we describe other users, or maybe you were referring to the editors of Etymonline, who simply give "another" as "[early 13c merger of **an** + **other**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/another#etymonline_v_13495)." (The entry for "other" does in fact show the "an-" roots you mention, though)

Answer (score 2):

They're not two words. They're **spelled** with a space, but that's just spelling, not language. Many languages don't space between words, or  -- what amounts to the same thing -- don't consider "words" the same as English does.

Spaces and spelling are irrelevant to actual language. Would an illiterate English speaker think of *at least* or *a lot* as two words?

Comment: I think a non-literate intelligent speaker would indeed regard *a lot* as two words because there are an, albeit very limited,  number of modifiers that can be used with *lot*. For example: *whole, huge, awful, very*.

Comment: I think this is a poor answer. They may represent a single concept, but they do it using two words -- words are the things we separate with spaces when writing.

Comment: @Barmar go ahead, define "word", do it, in under 512 characters, I dare you

Comment: From Lexico: "A single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing, used with others (or sometimes alone) to form a sentence and typically shown with a space on either side when written or printed." What you're describing I would call a "term".